# Why does setting a value for a generic setter property in typescript does not update the value of another property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to assign a new value to a setter of a concrete type of an abstract generic type at runtime. However, the value is not updated.
I debugged it and saw that instead of "executing the setter", a property with the setter's name is assigned the value. 
The value of the original property `description` doesn't change, although that's what I expected the setter to do.

It does not work when the type `Drawing` is coming from deserialized json resource.
I think it's because the json parser maps it to the interface and not the concrete class. But I have no idea how to fix it.

I have a concrete type of the abstract generic shown below.
The problem as stated above: The original description value does not get updated, it stays as an empty string.

```
interface Resource {
    id: string;
    type: string;
}
interface Drawing extends Resource {
    description: description;
}
interface description {
    type: "Text",
    value: string,
}
class Drawing implements Drawing {
    constructor(desc: string = "") {
        this.descriptionValue = desc;
    }
    set descriptionValue(desc: string) {
        this.description = {
            type: "Text",
            value: desc
        }
    }
}
abstract class Example<T extends Resource>{
    entites: T[] = [];

    updateAttributeValue<U extends keyof T>(attribute: U, id: string | number, newValue: any) {

        const entity = this.entites[0];
        entity[attribute] = newValue;
        console.log(entity) //still contains the old value for description if deserialized from json
    }
}
class DrawingExample extends Example<Drawing> {
    //some ctor parameters 
}

console.log("main");
const dEx = new DrawingExample(); 
const test = new Drawing(); //This works, but if the type Drawing is originated/deserialized from a JSON it does not
test.id = "112";
dEx.entites.push(test);
dEx.updateAttributeValue("descriptionValue", "1", "asdfasdf");
```

Comment: Please edit this code to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  As it stands there are errors and nothing is actually calling the `console.log()` line which presumably demonstrates your problem.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry. Had the wrong version of my code. I updated it and it seems odd, but in TS playground I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I could narrow down the problem. It appears only when the type is deserialized from json.